# curl ftp and text format between unix and mainframe

Tags: unix, curl, ftp

Am transferring a file from unix to mainframe using curl and ftp with --ssl-reqd.

File needs to be formatted to mainframe dataset.

FTP in a shell worked fine using quote site blksize=0 lrecl=80.

Without this the file is not formatted properly of course. How do I handle this using curl? I am not seeing where commands similar to blksize and lrecl are available when using curl.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the -Q option is what you're looking for:

```
curl -Q 'site blksize=0 lrecl=80' ...
```